# Redefining a variable in a loop does not make it undefined

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, redeclaration

Having the following for-loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    console.log(i, p);
    var p;
    p = 42;
}
```

I was expecting the output to be:

```
0 undefined
0 undefined
0 undefined
```

But actually, the output is:

```
0 undefined
0 42
0 42
```

Since we're using `var p` (to redeclare `p`) next line, why isn't `p` undefined (always) in the `console.log` line?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript, `there is no such thing as block level scope in js.`

Comment: @Bharadwaj Actually, in ES6 we have `let`.

Comment: @IonicăBizău yes, the example which is given by OP suites part of that answer.

Comment: Are you asking this out of curiosity? Hoisting-related issues like this won't be an issue if you declare variables at the top as you most likely should. This particular problem could have been analyzed quite easily by stepping through your code with a debugger. You would have noticed after "executing" the second `var p;` that the value of `p` did not change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

due to [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) and your variable being function scoped rather than block scoped.

your for loop is translated to

```
var p;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    console.log(i, p);
    p = 42;
}
```

which means first time p is accessed it is `undefined`,

Next time it is already initialized in the current function scope so it will be keep the initialized value.

Comment: @IonicăBizău got it! w3schools -> bad :) I thought it was adequately explaining the point though

Comment: Actually, not exactly. The `var p;` is hoisted **above** the for loop (to the top of whatever function it resides in).